# Can't get graphics card prices using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble getting the prices from graphics cards on newegg. I'm still pretty new to python and beautiful soup but this is what I got so far.

```
price_container = container.findAll("li" , {"class", "price-current"})

>>> price_container
[<li class="price-current">
<span class="price-current-label">
</span>$<strong>319</strong><sup>.99</sup> 
            <span class="price-current-range">
<abbr title="to">–</abbr>
</span>
</li>]
```

all I need is 319.99
but cant seem to figure out how to extract the text

Comment: try `price_container[0].find('span', {'class': 'price-current-label'}).text`

Comment: That seems to only print out \n

Comment: oh, i read the html wrong, try `price_container[0].text` you should get `319.99-`. then you may manually remove the hyphen by string slicing